# how to create duplicate checker across objects in apex

Tags: apex, visualforce, trigger

I want to write my own trigger that will check, on creation of a new record, the value of a field of that item against all records of a field of another object. The application would allow the trigger on creation of a record to find if there are any records in the other object with the same piece of information, in essence a duplicate field value checker.
So if I have an '`ObjectA__c`' and another '`ObjectB__c`' and each has a field '`field__c`' and I wanted to check that if a new record for ObjectA__c is being created it should trigger a check against all records of `Objectb__c` and compare the values in '`field__c`' and where there is match to set the value of another `fieldB__c` to a certain value. Is there a good example anywhere of this or so I need to code from the ground up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did this in a text editor so I haven't tested it or anything, but something like this should work.

You dont indicate in teh quwestion whether you are setting the value of the 'other' field to anything based on something on the ObjectB record or not, which is why I used a map and not just a set.  this wy you have access tot eh Object B records should you need them for any logic.

If the value of the new field isnt based ont he BObject record, then what I have below should work just fine

```
trigger myObjectATrigger on ObjectA__c(before insert){

    map<string,list<ObjectB__c>> BObjMap = new map<string,list<ObjectB__c>>();
    for(ObjectB__c b : [Select Id, Name, myField__c From ObjectB__c]){
        if(BObjMap.get(b.myField__c) == null){
            BObjMap.put(b.myField__c, new list<ObjectB__c>());
        }
        BObjMap.get(b.myField__c).add(b);
    }

    for(ObjectA__c a : trigger.new){
        if(BObjMap.containskey(a.myField__c)){
            a.OtherFieldToUpdate = //Whatever you want to update it to
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Its worth noting this will be limited by Gov Limits.  I tried to cut down the size of the object B records returned by only returning those that have myField values that mastch those in trigger.new, but theorectically, should you have a very large number of records that match that field, you could exceed the gov limits for your ObjectB list.  You could easily turn this into some sort of batchable process should you need to.

Comment: Was just writing this comment before I saw yours: A caution about code like this that has a loop inside a loop: the cost is exponential. When the data volumes grow, slow performance or worse governor limit violations will occur. So its worth coding up front to ensure the cost only grows linearly, usually by using maps (in this case keyed by the value being checked) holding lists of SObjects.

Comment: Agree totally.  I will update the code to use a map for the b object.  Was just busting out some psuedo code to start.

Comment: Updated the code to be more efficient

Comment: @Dunc44 that did the job really well, there was one typo: 'trigger.new' had one spare pair of brackets that did not need to be there. Thanks for that piece of code it saved me a lot of time!

Comment: yup, silly mistake.  Changed the code.  Glad it helped